# How to trigger next/prev from inside Ajax content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have a bunch of subpages, that I display as a gallery of Ajax popups with MagnificPopup, which works nicely except for one problem: On the pages themselves there are links to the previous/next page. I want to prevent their behaviour and make them trigger the popups previous/next buttons. I can't get that to work.

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="projects">
    <a class="details" href="index.php?id=12">Details Project 1</a>
    <a class="details" href="index.php?id=13">Details Project 2</a>
    <a class="details" href="index.php?id=14">Details Project 2</a>
</div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
$('.projects').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    delegate: 'a.details',
    alignTop: false,
    removalDelay: 300,
    callbacks: {
        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#content');
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            $('div.mfp-content #browselinks li.next a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.next(); });
            $('div.mfp-content #browselinks li.prev a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.prev();  });
        }
    },
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    disableOn: function() {
        return( $(window).width() >= 680) ;
    }
});
```

The links are selected correctly and I can prevent their default behaviour. Also, calling $.magnificPopup.next(); or $.magnificPopup.instance.next(); manually from the console works fine and makes MagnificPopup go to the next element, but clicking the links just causes the Popup to close. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your references to `#browselinks` in `ajaxContentAdded` indicate that your content has `ID=""` attributes with the same ID values. As you are loading multiple pages, into the current DOM, you will wind up with duplicate IDs.

You cannot differentiate between multiple *identical* IDs in HTML. All browsers can only see *the first occurrence*.

You could try changing it to avoid the ID:

e.g.

```
$('div.mfp-content li.next a')
```

But you need to make sure the new selector a) does not use IDs and b) is specific enough to find the elements.

Adding a `browselinks` *class* to the content pages would help, then you could have

```
$('div.mfp-content .browselinks li.next a')
```

As you just want to match content *newly added to the DOM*, you could just use delegated event handlers instead for the next buttons:

e.g.

```
$('.projects').on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.next a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.next(); });
$('.projects').on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.prev a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.prev();  });

$('.projects').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    delegate: 'a.details',
    alignTop: false,
    removalDelay: 300,
    callbacks: {
        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#content');
        }
    },
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    disableOn: function() {
        return( $(window).width() >= 680) ;
    }
});
```

This works by listening for the click events to bubble up, to a non-changing ancestor, then applying the jQuery selector. This means the elements only have to match/exist at click time and not when the event was registered.

if `.projects` is not an ancestor of the dynamically loaded pages, use `document` instead:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.next a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.next(); });
$(document).on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.prev a').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.prev();  });
```

### Update

based on the DOCS I have been looking at, the `$.magnificPopup.instance`, would be a better option to access methods like `next()` and `prev()`?

Which would make the code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.next a').click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.magnificPopup.instance.next(); 
});
$(document).on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.prev a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.magnificPopup.instance.prev();  
});
```

Comment: Good point, I replaced the id with a class name. But it doesn't help. The links get selected correctly, I tried that adding a style with .css('border','1px solid red')

Comment: @j4k3. Using delegated events handlers would be the other option. I will change my example.

Comment: Oh, I also tried to remotely trigger .trigger('click') on MagnificPopups prev/next buttons. No luck either.

Comment: @j4k3: Are you able to post a functional example (e.g. to a JSFiddle)?

Comment: @j4k3: Looking at the docs, should you be using `$.magnificPopup.next()`, or doing `$('.projects').magnificPopup('next')` instead?

Comment: or `$.magnificPopup.instance.next()`?

Comment: I'd love to provide an example, but i cant figure out how to get the links into content that jsfiddle can load via an Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I got it running with a delegate like so: $(document).on('click', 'div.mfp-content .browselinks li.next a', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); $.magnificPopup.instance.next(); });

Comment: After close. when open popup and use next, prev skip some items. any solution?